# My Value won't text align center

Tags: javascript, html, css

Can anyone please help me understand why this text value of "7" is not centering?

```
<input id="button7" value="7" onclick='Calc.Input.value += "7"' type="button" class="button"/>
```

For the web version the 7 is centering, but not the mobile version through media querying.

My Media Query CSS only is;

```
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 320px) and (max-device-width : 568px) {

.set_1 {
  height: 270px;
  width: auto;
}

.set_2 {
  height: 266px;
  width: auto;
}

.set_3 {
  height: 266px;
  width: auto;
}

.set_4 {
  height: 266px;
  width: auto;
}

.set_5 {
  height: 266px;
  width: auto;
}

.text_box{
  height: 180px;
  width: 730px;
  font-size: 100px;
}

.button {
  height:200px;
  width:200px;
  font-size: 100px;
  text-align: center;
}

}
```

Comment: So can you post the media query?

Comment: Can you show us the media query?

Comment: Maybe a CSS definition is overriding your `text-align:center` in the mobile version. Are any additional style sheets loaded for the mobile version?

Comment: only the regular css and media query stylesheet (in one file), which I posted as requested.

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue. Any chance you can create a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) to illustrate the problem (or share a link to your working page)?

Comment: I did it in a jsfiddle; http://jsfiddle.net/PUDq8/.  the text looks centered here; however, on my iphone 5 mobile device, the text is not align center.

Answer (score 0):

add:

```
display: block;
```

I believe....